# How do I enable the "Other" user for login with Active Directory?

Tags: lightdm, active-directory

So I work at a university using active directory, and in my office there are a few computers that I've set up, in Ubuntu 11.10, to log as an AD user.

In order to log in a person just needs to use the "other" user at login and use their university ID and Password. I've installed 12.04LTS on my personal computer, and I see that the "other" option no longer exists.

If I upgrade those computers who need AD login capabilities, will they have them?

Comment: I also join my test machine to the domain with likewise, and in terminal doing "su - <user>" it works fine, but still don't have the "other" in X login.

Comment: Being new to Ubuntu...I had no idea someone this was turned off default. Thanks for the tip of fixing the issue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and add the following line :

```
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

Then restart lightdm :

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me.

Comment: For later versions of Ubuntu (14.04) add this line to: `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf`

Comment: @L.D.James 's solution still works on 18.04.

Answer (score 7):

You can also hide all users so that you enter whatever name you want by editing /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf adding :

```
greeter-hide-users=true
```

This is particularly useful if you use NIS or LDAP services.

Answer (score 6):

For Ubuntu 16.04 configuration for greeters is taken from the configuration files in the following hierarchy:

1. /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf
2. /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf
3. /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

The place to add your configuration changes is the second in the list, provided that there is nothing in the last list file to override the values you wish to change.

So, creating a file ***/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-myconfig.conf*** and putting in it

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-hide-users=false
greeter-show-manual-login=true
allow-guest=false
```

- First entry hides the list of login users
- Second entry allows manual user login
- Third entry disables the guest login account

NOTE: For Ubuntu versions prior to ***15.10*** replace **[Seat:*]** with **[SeatDefaults]**

When changes have been made, restart the lightdm service to have the changes applied.

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service
```

For more information see: [Ubuntu LightDM Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM)

Answer (score 1):

From the Ubuntu wiki:  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

> LightDM configuration is governed by the lightdm.conf file, however it's not suppose to be directly edited, instead use:
>
> lightdm-set-defaults

I found the file at /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults

At the terminal you would enter:

`sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -m true`

Edit: While this was true temporarily for 12.04, it seems to not be true for any newer release, and editing conf files as otherwise suggested is the correct solution.

Comment: This utility (lightdm-set-defaults) does not exist on my system, and I can't figure out how to install it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/251041/how-to-install-lightdm-set-defaults did not help, either.

Comment: @foobarbecue, check that topic again. It appears things have changed with v14.04, and lightdm-set-defaults has been deprecated.

Comment: Not just deprecated, removed, according to  http://askubuntu.com/questions/251041/how-to-install-lightdm-set-defaults/466656#466656