# Ubuntu 12.04 login screen with LDAP users, no "other..."

Tags: login, ldap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable the “Other” user for login with Active Directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121124/how-do-i-enable-the-other-user-for-login-with-active-directory)

We've upgraded recently to Ubuntu 12.04 desktop and have issue with the new login screen. When users are listed there is now no option for "Other..." allowing a username and a password to be entered. Given our users are all living in LDAP with uids well above 1000, this means it is now impossible to login via the GUI.

To workaround we've had to set the greeter-hide-users option to true in lightdm.conf. This works but means we have to enter the username every time. In 11.04 this was not necessary - "other..." would allow first-time logging in and thereafter the login screen would throw up these LDAP users, presumably using a "recently used" cache?

Hopefully the answer is some obvious setting I've missed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the required option in lightdm.conf is:

```
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

We are using it with CentrifyDC, and it works great!