# Login Manager does not have a selection for other user

Tags: login, lightdm

I have a problem with the login manager of ubuntu 12.04, it does not have a selection to login another user; instead it only allows administrator and guest.

Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Have you added a user?

Comment: actually i cannot login another user from the network

Comment: he mean , have you created another user actually . you did not mention in your Question that you are trying to login from the Network . please make sure about the Question that you have mentioned all the deatails need by the question .

Comment: i did not create another user, the problem was there was no way to login another user because in the login only Administrator and Guest are in the selection there was no selection for another user so there was no way to login the root account

Comment: how can I login using root because there was no selection in the login window for root and other user

Comment: Similar question asked and answered in this [thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141009/how-to-enable-the-other-user-login-in-ubuntu-12-04-if-the-userid-i-want-to-use).

Comment: Can you login using the virtual terminal(Ctrl+Alt+F1)? It is text-only.

Comment: Do you mean the 'Other' option to log in an unlisted user? Check this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/128280/ubuntu-12-04-login-screen-with-ldap-users-no-other

Answer (score 0):

Which architecture do you run Ubuntu on? This looks also like the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/accountsservice/+bug/952909?comments=all which affects accountsservice on some architectures like ARM (e.g., on Toshiba AC100) or PPC. It has already been fixed in the original Debian packages, but not yet in Ubuntu's packages AFAIK.

If that's the case, read also [User Accounts not listed in System Settings User Accounts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147536/12-04-user-accounts-not-listed-in-system-settings-user-accounts), a question where the architecture has been explicitly stated.