# How do I log in with a user that is not included on the list in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, login-screen, unity-greeter

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. I have created a system user so as to keep it out of the login screen with `sudo adduser --group --system markpaskal`, but I cannot login from the greeter because there is no 'Other' option.

Short of stopping lightdm and using startx from a virtual terminal, do I have any way of logging in to this account? Should I be seeing the 'Other' option?

Comment: At the Login screen  , try logging through **tty** as `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and enter the details , then `Alt+F7` back , i can't confirm if it works.

Comment: Didn't work. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this.  But this post might help:

[Ubuntu 12.04 login screen with LDAP users, no "other..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128280/ubuntu-12-04-login-screen-with-ldap-users-no-other)

check the answer by "Clausi"

Hope this helps